# Error passing a `time_t` and `struct tm`, ESP32

Tags: esp32, time

I need to create a converter from epoch time stored in a `time_t` variable, to a `struct tm` variable, in order to check / create a certain task every hour or a day. This function should get also a past `time_t` for other uses.

Converting function, inside a library, works OK ( last two lines are for verification purposes, meaning conversion was done as expected ):

```
void myIOT32::convEpoch(time_t in_time, struct tm *convTime)
{
  convTime = gmtime(&in_time);
  char time_char[40];
  sprintf(time_char, "%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", convTime->tm_year + 1900, convTime->tm_mon+1, convTime->tm_mday,
            convTime->tm_hour, convTime->tm_min, convTime->tm_sec);

  Serial.print(" from funct: ");
  Serial.println(time_char);
```

Now, when calling it from my code and try to use time `tm` var, it causes the code to crash. In code below, I just try to print it to console:

```
void sendnewNotif()
{
  struct tm *newtime;
  time_t t=182423032;
  iot.convEpoch(t, newtime); // <--- Using the conversion
  char timeStamp[50];
  // Serial.print(newtime->tm_year); 

}
```

What may be the problem ?

Guy

Comment: `struct tm newtime;` to alocate on stack. `struct tm *newtime` is a pointer to nowhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
void myIOT32::convEpoch(time_t in_time, struct tm *convTime)
{
  convTime = gmtime(&in_time);
```

Here you are overwriting the parameter `convTime`. There is no point in
passing such a parameter if you are not going to use the value provided.

```cpp
void sendnewNotif()
{
  struct tm *newtime;
  time_t t=182423032;
  iot.convEpoch(t, newtime); // <--- Using the conversion
```

`newtime` is initially uninitialized. The call to `iot.convEpoch()`
doesn't change that (the parameter is passed by value, not by
reference).

```cpp
  Serial.print(newtime->tm_year);
```

This is dereferencing an uninitialized pointer, which is undefined
behavior and can crash the program.

The simplest solution I see is to have `myIOT32::convEpoch()` return the
pointer it got from `gmtime()`. Note that this points to static storage,
which makes the method not reentrant.

Example (not tested):

```cpp
struct tm *myIOT32::convEpoch(time_t in_time)
{
  struct tm *convTime = gmtime(&in_time);
  // ...
  return convTime;
}

void sendnewNotif()
{
  time_t t = 182423032;
  struct tm *newtime = iot.convEpoch(t);
  Serial.print(newtime->tm_year); 
}
```

Comment: thank you for your kind and comprehensive reply :), but your answer rised some more: a) why does it matter if it is initialized ? since it get its value later on ( though as a pointer ). b) are there guide lines when to use as a return value ( as you just suggested ) or as I did, passing its value/ reference ( in a case it works as expected... ) ?

Comment: a) It does not get it's value later on. b) You could in principle pass the pointer by reference, but mixing pointers and references can quickly become highly confusing.