# Fail to convert time_T from past to tm struct

Tags: esp32, time

Continuing a [Question asked few days ago](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/76290/error-passing-a-time-t-and-struct-tm-esp32), answered by Edgar, a new question has rised:

My goal was using a **past** `time_t` value, and convert it into a `struct tm` variable in order to  use it, part as a `Char` to print a readable text and some for logic queries.

At start NTP is configured as:

```
void myIOT32::startNTP(const int gmtOffset_sec = 2 * 3600, const int daylightOffset_sec = 3600, const char *ntpServer = "pool.ntp.org")
{
  configTime(gmtOffset_sec, daylightOffset_sec, ntpServer);
}
```

and every-time I need to get epoch and or `struct tm` of **current** time I call this function

```
void myIOT32::getTime()
{
  int a = 0;
  while (a < 3)
  {
    if (getLocalTime(&timeinfo))
    {
      delay(100);
      time(&epoch_time);
    }
    a++;
  }
```

BUT, when using the following function I get not GMT (+3) reference as needed :

```
struct tm *myIOT32::convEpoch(time_t in_time)
{
  struct tm *convTime = gmtime(&in_time);
  //char time_char[40];
  //sprintf(time_char, "%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", convTime->tm_year + 1900, convTime->tm_mon + 1, convTime->tm_mday,
          convTime->tm_hour, convTime->tm_min, convTime->tm_sec);
  return convTime;
}
```

Meaning I get to correct epoch time, but `strcut tm` is 3 hrs earlier ( and no, I do not want to hard-code `+3`... )

Comment: the Arduino and the NTP server don't know the time zone you are in. so create a constant and put it at the beginning of your sketch (yes, hardcode). why do you use the C time library? the TimeLib is much simpler to use

Comment: @Juraj - even tough it was config at the beginning when `start NTP` was executed ?

Comment: @Juraj  and the reason I do not want to hard code +3, is daylight saving...

Comment: in Europe it looks like we have only a few changes to/from DST before us. the date can be calculated. https://github.com/jandrassy/Regulator/blob/104421279aef672362bcff0baf7447410bc2b590/Regulator/Modbus.ino#L94

Comment: @Juraj Yes... that was my fallback. By the way, you asked about the reason not using `TimeLib`... since in example called "simpleTime" for ESP32 used dates that way ( and not as in ESP8266), so I guessed it is a compatibility issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replacing `gmtime(&timeinfo)` with `localtime(&timeinfo)` in `myIOT32::convEpoch` passes definition of time-zone as needed.

for more information [in this cpluspls site](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/gmtime/)